# Android Kotlin pass data from base fragment of a viewpager to one of its tab fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager

So in this case, I have a fragment that act as the base fragment for a viewpager consisting two tabs. What I want to do is to pass an information from the base fragment to one of it's tab fragment.

This is the snippet code of the base fragment

**BaseFragment.kt**

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    val args = arguments?.let { SwitchingHistoryDetailFragmentArgs.fromBundle(it) }

    val selectedOrderId = args?.orderId          //This variable is the one that i want to pass.

    // Set action bar title to "Main Dashboard"
    (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "Switching History Details"

    val binding: FragmentSwitchingHistoryDetailBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,
        R.layout.fragment_switching_history_detail, container, false)


    Log.i("History", "Selected History: $selectedOrderId")


    binding.viewpagerMain.adapter =
        MyPagerAdapter((activity as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager)
    binding.tabsMain.setupWithViewPager(viewpager_main)


    return binding.root
}
```

As you can see above, the variable that i want to pass is that `selectedOrderId`. This is the tab fragment that I want pass that information into:

**DetailFragment.kt**

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    // Binding object for this fragment and the layout
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,
        R.layout.fragment_switching_history_detail_tab, container, false)

        ....
        ....
        ....

    //Return.... i don't know.
    return binding.root
}
```

And this is the PagerAdapter I'm using:

**MyPagerAdapter.kt**

```
class MyPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager): FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm){

    // sebuah list yang menampung objek Fragment
    private val pages = listOf(
        DetailFragment(), <- This is where i want to pass the information into
        DetailFragment2()
    )

    // menentukan fragment yang akan dibuka pada posisi tertentu
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return pages[position]
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return pages.size
    }

    // judul untuk tabs
    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return when(position){
            0 -> "Details"
            else -> "Previous Changes"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm quite new with viewPager. I tried to use Intent but does not work. Is there a way to achieve this? If there's any detail i miss to point out, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way is pass the `selectedOrderId` into the adapter like below:

```
binding.viewpagerMain.adapter =
        MyPagerAdapter((activity as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager,selectedOrderId)
```

then pass that orderId from `PagerAdapter` to fragment constructor like below:

```
class MyPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager,val orderId : String): FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm){

    // sebuah list yang menampung objek Fragment
    private val pages = listOf(
        DetailFragment.getInstance(orderId), <- This is where i want to pass the information into
        DetailFragment2()
    )

    // menentukan fragment yang akan dibuka pada posisi tertentu
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return pages[position]
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return pages.size
    }

    // judul untuk tabs
    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return when(position){
            0 -> "Details"
            else -> "Previous Changes"
        }
    }
}
```

Your Detail fragment looks like :

```
class DetailFragment : Fragment() { 

    private var orderId: String? = null


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    // Binding object for this fragment and the layout
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,
        R.layout.fragment_switching_history_detail_tab, container, false)



if (arguments != null) {
                orderId = arguments?.getString("orderId")
            }
// do whatever you want to do with this variable

    return binding.root
}

companion object {      

        /**
         * Method used to get the instance of the fragment.
         *
         * @return fragment instance
         */
        @JvmStatic
        fun getInstance(orderId: String): DetailFragment {
            val fragment = DetailFragment()
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putString("orderId", orderId)
            fragment.arguments = bundle
            return fragment
        }
    }
}
```

LET ME KNOW IF YOU HAVE ANY DOUBT IN THIS. HAPPY CODING :)

Comment: Sorry, It returns `Too many arguments for public constructor DetailFragment`. the `getInstance() ` is never used as well. Maybe i have to call it somewhere ?

Comment: In viewpager adapter, i have added that code please check

Comment: Many thanks man!!. It works! But you have to uncomment that `bundle.putString("orderId", orderId)` first. Just edit that answer.